# VS Studio Terminal Won't Come Up, Program Won't Start

Tags: c#, terminal

I'm trying to run a program I wrote in MS Visual Studio (mac)[image], and when I start the program without debugging, the terminal won't come up and the program won't start. An internal terminal pops up inside VS with the message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   Cohen_Brett_HW1.Program.CheckCode(String strInput) in
>   /Users/brettcohen/Desktop/MIS
>   333K/Cohen_Brett_HW1_WORKING/Cohen_Brett_HW1_WORKING/Program.cs:line
>   122    at Cohen_Brett_HW1.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   /Users/brettcohen/Desktop/MIS
>   333K/Cohen_Brett_HW1_WORKING/Cohen_Brett_HW1_WORKING/Program.cs:line
>   41

My code looks like this:

```
using System;

namespace Cohen_Brett_HW1
{
    class Program
    {
        //Named constants
        public const decimal TacoPrice = 2.00m;
        public const decimal SandwichPrice = 7.00m;
        public const decimal TaxRate = .0825m;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Input variables
            String strCustCodeInput;
            int intTacoCountInput;
            String strTacoCountInput;
            int intSandwichCountInput;
            String strSandwichCountInput;


            //Variable for customer code validity
            Boolean boolCodeValid;


            //Get the customer code
            do
            {
                //Request input
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the customer code:");
                strCustCodeInput = Console.ReadLine();

                //Make sure the code is valid
                boolCodeValid = CheckCode(strCustCodeInput);

            } while (boolCodeValid == false); //loop if customer code is invalid


            do
            {
                //Get the taco order count
                do
                {
                    //Request user input
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of tacos you would like to order:");

                    //Read the input
                    strTacoCountInput = Console.ReadLine();

                    //Pass the string to CheckItem method and assign the result to intTacoCountInput
                    intTacoCountInput = CheckItem(strTacoCountInput);
                } while (intTacoCountInput == -1); //Loop if they enter an invalid number


                //Get the sandwich order count
                do
                {   //Request user input
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of sandwiches you would like to order:");

                    //Read the input
                    strSandwichCountInput = Console.ReadLine();

                    //Pass the string to CheckItem method and assign the result to intTacoCountInput
                    intSandwichCountInput = CheckItem(strSandwichCountInput);

                } while (intSandwichCountInput == -1); //Loop if they enter an invalid number

                if (intTacoCountInput + intSandwichCountInput == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Total number of items ordered must be greater than 0." + "\n");

                }
            } while (intTacoCountInput + intSandwichCountInput < 1); //make sure that total items ordered is at least one


            //Output variables

            //Total item count
            int intTotalItemCount = intTacoCountInput + intSandwichCountInput;

            //Taco subtotal
            decimal TacoSubtotal = TacoPrice * intTacoCountInput;

            //Sandwich subtotal
            decimal SandwichSubtotal = SandwichPrice * intSandwichCountInput;

            //Combined Subtotal
            decimal CombinedSubtotal = TacoSubtotal + SandwichSubtotal;

            //Tax Amount
            decimal TaxAmount = CombinedSubtotal * TaxRate;

            //Grand Total
            decimal GrandTotal = CombinedSubtotal + TaxAmount;

            //Console output
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Code: " + strCustCodeInput.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine("Total Items: " + intTotalItemCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Taco Subtotal: " + (TacoSubtotal.ToString("C")));
            Console.WriteLine("Sandwich Subtotal: " + (SandwichSubtotal.ToString("C")));
            Console.WriteLine("Full Subtotal: " + (CombinedSubtotal.ToString("C")));
            Console.WriteLine("Sales Tax: " + (TaxAmount.ToString("C")));
            Console.WriteLine("Grand Total: " + (GrandTotal.ToString("C")));

            //Keep console open
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        //This method validates the customer code
        public static Boolean CheckCode(String strInput)
        {
            if (strInput.Length < 4 || strInput.Length > 6)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a valid code, 4 to 6 characters, letters only." + "\n");
                return false;
            }

            else
            {   //make sure that input is letters only
                foreach (char c in strInput)
                {
                    if (!char.IsLetter(c))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Customer code must consist of letters only." + "\n");
                        return false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }


        //This method validates the customer selection
        static int CheckItem(String strInput)
        {
            //Establish integer variable
            int NowInt;

            //Convert the strInput to an integer
            NowInt = Convert.ToInt32(strInput);

            //Validate
            if (NowInt > -1)
            {
                return NowInt;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a valid number greater than or equal to 0." + "\n");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is line 41 in the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It looks like you pass `null` to your method `CheckCode`. You might want to check for null there.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  //Make sure the code is valid
                boolCodeValid = CheckCode(strCustCodeInput);

Comment: Did you debug the code to check why NullReferenceException is thrown? The error also says that line 122 in CheckCode method is throwing error. You need to check there too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jVJB7L) I was able to run your program just by placing `public` before your method `static void Main(string[] args)` and before `class Program`. I also changed your `CheckCode` method because there wasn't a proper validation to check if there would only be letters.

Follow the link provided to check the full code otherwise just add `public` where I told you, add this library `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` and modify your `CheckCode` method to match this:

```
public static Boolean CheckCode(String strInput)
{
    if (strInput.Length < 4 || strInput.Length > 6)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a valid code, 4 to 6 characters, letters only." + "\n");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {   //make sure that input is letters only
        return Regex.IsMatch(strInput, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    }
}
```